# setData is not a function + Angular2-Highcharts

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I was following simple example to set data to Highcharts using this [Angular2-Highcharts](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts) module

As shown in the following [example](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts#dynamic-interaction-with-chart-object), i have made small tweak to dynamically set data to Highcharts. Following is the code snippet :

```
constructor() {
    this.options = {
      chart: { type: 'spline' },
      title: { text : 'dynamic data example'},
      series: [{ data: [2,3,5,8,13] }]
    };

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.chart.series[0].setData([21,31,51,81,13]);
    }, 3000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.chart.series.push({data:[]});
      this.chart.series[1].setData([100,200,300]);
    }, 5000);
}
```

[Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/SjLmKc?p=preview) for the same .

**Error :**

```
ERROR TypeError: _this.chart.series[1].setData is not a function
    at eval (run.plnkr.co/QZBbWi3BVy3DeOzT/app/main.ts!transpiled:28)
```

**My Observation :**

What is evident with that error is there is no setData function in the `series` array in the 1st element. Alternate approach to resolve this is, initializing `this.options` with empty object with `data` property :

```
constructor() {
        this.options = {
          chart: { type: 'spline' },
          title: { text : 'dynamic data example'},
          series: [{ data: [2,3,5,8,13] },
                   { data: [] },
                  ]
        };
}
```

This is very crude way as i need to do the same for 50 elements in `this.options.series` if i see them coming dynamically

Is there any efficient and better approach to resolve this error ?

**PS :** Am new to Highcharts, so please bear with me if am doing something completely wrong at basic level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setData modifies a series which already exists - if you do not have the series you cannot modify it.

If you want to add a new series, you should use [chart.addSeries()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.addSeries) method like this:

```
   setTimeout(() => {
      this.chart.addSeries({
          data: [21,31,51,81,13]
      });
    }, 5000);
```

example: http://plnkr.co/edit/61IgH8t3YKjtIOgzpUPB?p=preview